# Couldn't pass parameter "smm" to the specified path

Tags: django

```
<li><a href="{%url 'corebloc_app:service_type%} smm">Marketing & Management Services</a></li>
```

This is the HTML code, trying to pass the string "smm" to this:

```
path("services/<str:service_type>", views.service_type, name="service_type")
```

So that I could have a path "services/smm" on my address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url template tag should be:

```
<li><a href="{%url 'corebloc_app:service_type' smm %}">Marketing & Management Services</a></li>
```

so you *include* the `smm` in the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url). If you want to use `smm` as *string*, you use:

```
<li><a href="{%url 'corebloc_app:service_type' 'smm' %}">Marketing & Management Services</a></li>
```